# Showing several pictures in a web application by selecting checkbox options

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, vue.js

I am creating a web-based (HTML, CSS, Javascript, VueJs) anatomy tool. I have a list of body parts as checklists. I also have a body image that gets its organs added to it when clicking on the checklist.

For example if you click on the "Left-Hand" option on the checklist then left-hand will be added to the picture of the body.

Now I want to know:

1-How do I put the body part pictures in the place and angle that I want them to be in.

2-How to setup the code so by clicking on the checklist, the respective body part is added to the body image?

Comment: We would need to see a [minimum, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before we could help you any further really, this is too broad as it stands.

Answer (score 1):

You could just absolutely position the images - if the images are png files with transparent backgrounds, you can rotate them to make them fit anywhere you need on the page and they will appear seamless. You can do this whole thing using just css. Without an example it makes it hard to give you a definitive answer, but if you start with the item so that it is positioned above the page at

```
position: absolute;
top:-400px;
```

*Then once the checkbox is checked, you can toggle the class, and the new class can have styles such as -*

```
position: absolute;
top: 37px;
left: 283px;
transform: rotate(20deg);
```

Answer (score -1):

Divide the whole body picture into smaller parts and arrange it with grid system. For example, divide the picture into 9*12 pieces and show/hide pictures on checklist clicking.